# Evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(a+2b\cos u)^2}{2b(a+b\cos u)}du$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was trying to evaluate explicitly the Willmore energy for Clifford torus, and I'm now stuck with this integral (it is the question 16 in chapter 3 of Kuhnel's Differential Geometry book) Can someone help me with this calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use formulas with  $t=tan (u/2)$ that will transform the integrand into a rational expression : $cos (u)=(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$ and $du=2dt/(1+t^2)$

Answer (score 0):

$$(a+2b\cos u)^2=a^2+4ab\cos u+4b^2\cos^2u=(a+b\cos u)4b\cos u+a^2$$

Now for $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{du}{a+\cos u},$  use [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#Euler_and_Weierstrass)